# Unable to get GRIDVIEW when new column added

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

This is my SEARCH Function with gridview.I'm not able to get gridview in Form remaining all are fine.Here i added new columns two.Please help me out.thanks

```
private void txtSearch02()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ItemCode,ItemName,PointsNeeded from tb_ItemRedemption where (ItemCode is null or ItemCode='" + txtkey2.Text.Trim() + "') or (ItemName is null or ItemName='" + txtkey2.Text.Trim() + "')", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        Session["ItemCode"] = dt;
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        con.Close();
        dt.Columns.Add("Quantity");
        dt.Columns.Add("TotalPoints");

        // for caliculation 
        txtPointsNeeded.Text = dt.Rows[0]["PointsNeeded"].ToString();
        //dt.Rows[0]["Quantity"].ToString();
        //dt.Rows[0]["TotalPoints"].ToString();
        DataRow dr;
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        // for caliculation 
        txtGetQuantity.Text = txtQuantity.Text;
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
       GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.Visible = true;


    }
```

Comment: what is the error? and does your GridView1 has new columns (Quantity and TotalPoints). If not then you have to generate them manually. Btw how are you generating column for your grid i.e Auto or Manually?

Comment: my error like Its keep on Repeating Execution and finally "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" at sda.Fill(ds) and Columns Manually i did sir.

Comment: set `GridView1.Visible = true;` before `GridView1.DataSource = dt;`

Comment: What are you trying to do with DataRow dr? Your creating it as a blank new row in dt and then immediately adding it to the table with nothing in it.

Comment: It's also good practice to use parameters in your query rather than client side inputs like text from a textbox etc to avoid sql injection. See here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter also shows how to use the 'using(){}' statement.

Comment: @sr28 my intention is to get gridview with  3 fields selected in table and 2 additional fields dats it..sir..

Comment: Are you sure the dataset is returning values? You're adding the 2 columns correctly. You seem to be adding a blank datarow for some reason but that shouldn't be stopping the GridView1 from showing values. Have you put a breakpoint on dt = ds.Tables[0] to see if anything is being returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from my comments regarding parameterising the query and using the 'using(){}' statement I'd start by writing something like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myStr))
{
    string sql = "select ItemCode,ItemName,PointsNeeded from tb_ItemRedemption where (ItemCode is null or ItemCode = @txtkey2) or (ItemName is null or ItemName = @txtkey2)";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@txtkey2", txtkey2.Text.Trim());

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    //You're currently adding a blank DataTable to a session variable below as you've not 
    //filled it yet. I've left this incase that's what you meant to do.
    Session["ItemCode"] = dt;

    con.Open();

    //SqlDataAdapter should be able to fill a DataTable as well as a dataset.
    sda.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) //Put a breakpoint here to check if anything is returned in dt
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Quantity");
        dt.Columns.Add("TotalPoints");

        // for caliculation 
        txtPointsNeeded.Text = dt.Rows[0]["PointsNeeded"].ToString();

        //Not sure what you're trying to do here. You're just adding a blank row to dt.
        DataRow dr;
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        // for caliculation 
        txtGetQuantity.Text = txtQuantity.Text;

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        //Code to handle nothing being returned.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have previous three columns (with bindvalue) and add other two columns, It would be confusing one for it.
Add all the columns to datatable again. means three and new two.

Try it. It should work.cause your code is right.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure your Auto Generated Columns is set to 'true'.

Go to properties of grid view, and change auto generated columns to true in case of false.

Go through the links for further clarification : [Click here](http://forums.asp.net/t/990661.aspx?How%20to%20add%20and%20hide%20columns%20in%20a%20Gridview%20with%20AutoGenerateColumns%20true%20)